# Laravel (HasMany) doesnt rectrieve values

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following models:

```
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class forum_category extends Model
{
    //

    protected $table = 'forum_category';

    public function posts()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\forum_post');
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class forum_post extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'forum_post';


    public function category()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\forum_category');
    }
}
```

in my controller i attempt to get all categories with their posts:

```
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;

use App\forum_category as forum_category;


class ForumController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index ()
    {

        $categories = forum_category::all();

        return view('forum', ['categories' => $categories]);
    }

    public function createPost()
    {

    }

    public function createReply()
    {

    }
}
```

However it seems to only be returning my categories.

Can someone tell me what ive done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
$categories = forum_category::with('posts')->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

If you have `category_id` in the `forum_post` table, this will load categories with related posts.

Then just iterate over the collection to get posts:

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->posts as $post)
        {{ $post->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Also, the relationship should be:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\forum_category');
}
```

Comment: when i try this i get: Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Comment: @MarcRasmussen I've updated the answer. You need to fix the relationship too.

Comment: The same goes for the post relation in the category model. You missed to return it.